# Writing data in Excel deletes the existing data using Epplus

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I tried to change the value of a cell in an excel file with existing data using EPPLUS but it deletes all the content. The cell that i'd modifed was not also updated. Below is my code:

```
Dim fileInfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(newfilename)
Dim p As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(fileInfo)
Dim myWorksheet As ExcelWorksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
myWorksheet.Cells("A1").Value = "Data 1"
p.Save()
```

What should be the problem with the above code?

Comment: Why tag this excel - this is an Epplus issue...

Comment: Tested your snippet. It works just fine. It opens the document, changes a cell value and saves the file with all the other content still there.

Comment: Is your file somehow readonly or protected?  Any errors being swallowed or console logged?  Might want to call `p.Dispose()` to make sure it is being properly closed but probably not the problem.